# MongoDB - How to convert .or to aggregate equivalent when trying to find documents based on a query string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Example of a working response (`Tag` documents):

```
[ 
  { 
    _id: 5a27a6b09fe2c0057782199a,
    label: '05',
    createdBy: 5a27a66f4db90e0541315114,
    createdAt: 2017-12-06T08:17:09.480Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    __v: 0,
    occurrences: 1 
  }, 
  ...
]
```

This is my original code:

```
Tag.find({})
  .or({label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')})
  .sort(config.sortBy)
  .limit(config.limit)
  .skip(config.offset)
  .exec((err, tags) => {});
```

This works brilliantly, however I came across a scenario where this approach wasn't going to work (unrelated to the question).

This rewritten code is going to also include the `Page` documents, specifically the `tags` array. Here's an example `Page` document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a27a6b09fe2c00577821999"),
  "organisation" : ObjectId("5a17eb11bf3f990b94c01735"),
  "createdBy" : ObjectId("5a27a66f4db90e0541315114"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-06T08:13:36.199Z"),
  "updatedBy" : ObjectId("5a27a66f4db90e0541315114"),
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-06T08:18:20.809Z"),
  "tags" : [ 
    ObjectId("5a27a6b09fe2c0057782199a"), 
    ObjectId("5a27a7859fe2c005778219a6"), 
    ObjectId("5a27a7859fe2c005778219a4")
  ],
  "content" : "asd",
  "description" : "asdasd",
  "title" : "testing tag creation",
  "parent" : null,
  "__v" : 0
}
```

So this is what I have now:

```
Page.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },

  // This bit ain't working
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [{
        label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')
      }]     
    }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tags", 
      occurrences: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags", 
      localField: "_id", 
      foreignField: "_id", 
      as: "tagsData" 
    }
  },
  {$limit: config.limit},
  {$skip: config.offset},
  {$sort: {[config.sortBy]: config.order}},
  {
    $project: {
      occurrences: "$occurrences",
      tagData: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$tagsData", 0 
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "tagData._id": "$_id", 
      "tagData.occurrences": "$occurrences" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $replaceRoot: { 
      newRoot: "$tagData" 
    } 
  }
  ], (err, tags) => {
    console.log(tags);
  });
```

What I'm trying to do is replace this bit:

```
.or({label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')})
```

With the equivalent in the aggregate framework.

My attempt above always yields an empty array, even if I do `$match: {label: '05'}` for example I get no results.

I've been checking the docs but they aren't that obvious to me since this is the first time I'm working with aggregation.

I've looked at these two:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/

So my question is what am I doing wrong with the query bit?

Comment: Few things. The original query `Tag.find({}).or({label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')})` makes no sense to me. `Tag.find({})` matches all documents so any `.or` after that are redundant. Same applies to the aggregation match stage. The docs you are referring to read the `$or` array has at least 2 elements. Finally, your aggregation is way more complex than the original query. It uses 2 collection, so it would be advisable to provide an example doc from the second collection as well.

Comment: @AlexBlex It's not redundant, the `.or` will filter out results that doesn't match the query string. If this is the correct way of doing it I don't know, but the operator is there for a reason so I assume that you can do it this way. The array has more than 1 element in it but I cut them out, see the `...` bit in the example. I have included the `Page` document now, have a look.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it wont. You confuse `or` which is logical disjunction, boolean `+`, or alteration, whatever term you prefer, with `and` which is logical conjunction, boolean `*`, or intersection. The former doesn't limit anything that matches previous condition.

Comment: @AlexBlex Then why does it return what I expect it to? Regardless, since that's the old code, the question is more about how to rewrite it.

Comment: The "previous" code returns you everything. If you happy with it, just remove the matching stage in the pipeline. I believe the problem is in the lookup stage, and if you provide an example document from page collection you are querying there I could give you more practical advice. The schema you added to the question is not exactly a document that you are trying to `join` with the tag in the question.

Comment: @AlexBlex What you get in the callback as `tags` isn't "everything", that's what I'm trying to say. I added an example document.

Comment: Well, if you can reliable reproduce the query `Tag.find({}).or({label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')})` doesn't return entire collection, it would be a good reason to report a bug, but let's keep it aside. None of the 'tags' in the example page document match the example tag document. Could you ensure you follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve recommendations.  If I change one of the `tags` in the page document to `5a27a7859fe2c005778219a7`, would it still truly represent your dataset?

Comment: @AlexBlex Ah ye I've been testing a lot so data changes and so does the `_id`s, you can set whatever `_id` you wish and it will still represent the issue. Edit: I updated the question again.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments `Tag.find({}).or({label: new RegExp(config.query, 'i')})` makes  no sense to me, nor most of the aggregation pipeline.

There are few obvious problems in the pipeline that I will aim in the answer:

- `Page` has only Id's of tags, so `$match` by tag label should be done after `$lookup` stage, where labels become available.
- there is no need to `$unwind` before `$lookup` since v3.3
- `$lookup` itself refers to wrong fields `localField: "_id"` is _id of the page, which would hardly match any document in the tags collection
- it is not clear whether `$group` should count tags, or pages. I am assuming the former in the answer below.
- all the transformation stages - hard to guess the intentions, so I excluded them from the snippet below. Also removed sort-limit stages for brevity.

The shell query to count how many times tags with labels that match regexp `/05/i` were used on all pages:

```
db.pages.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags", 
      localField: "tags", 
      foreignField: "_id", 
      as: "tagsData" 
    }
  },
  {
      $unwind: "$tagsData"
  },
  { 
      $match: {
          "tagsData.label": /05/i
      }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tagsData", 
      occurrences: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Ok, that works. Had to change some stuff further down to accommodate for the unwinding of `tagsData` for it to work. Any idea why the sorting doesn't seem to do anything? I do `$sort: {label: 1 (or -1)}` but it has no effect what so ever.

Comment: Because there is no `label` to sort on? If you do sort after `$group` it must be `$sort: {"_id.label": 1 (or -1)}`.

Comment: Moving the sort to the bottom works. Also I noticed that `localField: "tags"` should really be `localField: "_id"` or it breaks, so I'll edit your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but it is totally wrong. Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match I already explained in the answer above why `localField: "_id"` is wrong. I revert your change, and welcome you to post your own answer, that you think resolves your problem.

Comment: I'm only telling you what is working and what is not, your solution isn't working so I cannot accept it then. I understand your explanation why it shouldn't work, but I cannot say why your solution isn't working and using `_id` is.

Comment: Fair enough, that's why I suggested you can answer the question yourself since you discovered what works for you.  The beauty of SO is that it can have multiple answers to cover all universes - the ones where `$or` limit result of previous filter and `$lookup` joins by `_id` in both collections, and the ones where such things never happen. Glad my answer helped you, and the only thing I ask is to leave it as is for the sake of people from my side of sanity who may read it in the future.